# A production database was destroyed from another tf state file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was surprised when a production database was destroyed when applying a TF in another project. I don't understand why this occurred, so any insight would be appreciated. Here are the facts:

The projects have different `terraform backend "s3" keys`. So the `tfstate` for both are entirely separate. This is in one AWS account.

Both projects (different repositories) specify a `module "database"` which contains a `resource "aws_db_instance" "hive_metastore"` .

Inside of this resource, the `indentifier` & `tags` (including `Name`) are wildly different. The `name` is the same, but this is now deprecated (in favor of `db_name`), and only specifies an initial database to create.

The only thing they share is the same semantic naming scheme of `resource "aws_db_instance" "hive_metastore"` and the `module "database"` definition (albeit separate repos), but I was under the impression this was just for referencing inside the tf scripts and not necessarily a key stored inside the tf state , and even if it was, there would be a unique binding behind the scenes. Is it the case resource blocks need unique names themselves across an entire cloud architecture (e.g. aws)?

My impression:
I could have `resource "aws_instance" "main"` with a `tag name foo` in one repo, then a `resource resource "aws_instance" "main"` with a `tag name bar` in another and we'd be good to go.

Comment: Strange ! , check the module database if they accidentally have a configuration block of the s3 backend, this is the only case I can think of

Comment: Unfortunately the new project explicitly uses a new terraform.backend.s3.key. It's extremely strange to me the same tf file uses the same 3 variables, and correctly interpolates the subnet group the rds relies on, but the rds instance itself does not use the new identifier to create a new instance, but instead grabs the other project's rds instance as the state and then overwrites it.

Comment: aah i see, did you check if the module database also defines its own backend configuration ?

Comment: I've never used such functionality. At the top-level I specify a `terraform.tf` that declares the `terraform.backend.s3.key`. I assumed it propagates to the "children" at the same level (e.g. I have a `main.tf` that holds the modules that are build from the supplied resource file).

Comment: but you said : "Both projects (different repositories) specify a module "database" which contains a resource "aws_db_instance" "hive_metastore" " , so my question is does the database module define its s3 terraform backend ?

Comment: No. The directory strictly holds an `rds.tf` (that specifies the aws db instance and  db subnet group) and a `variables.tf`. The variables tf are just declarations, the variables are fed in the top level `main.tf` that holds module declarations such as `module "database" { source = "./database", project = var.project}` 

Do the directories that hold my module also need terraform.backend.s3 specifically defined or will it inherit it from the parent?

Comment: Here is an imgur link showing my structure, hopefully it's clear [link](https://imgur.com/a/x60I9gY)

Comment: no, the child module which is in this case database module should NOT define its own backend configuration, and instead defined in the root module, i asked you this question to know why the database has been deleted by another root module ! we can't help with the given info, hide any sensitive information and reference the Terraform code here